# Could someone help me change the media query from max-width to min-width?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am asking if someone could help me change this medium length CSS code to have a min-width media query instead of max-width, when I try changing it, I get confused throughout the process as it is not mine, I just edited it. Also I attached the HTML code which corresponds to the CSS.

Thank you in advance!

```css
#logo {
    color: #E4E4EC;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-left: 54px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {

    color: #E4E4EC;
    background-color: #4A2285;
    border-radius: 13px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-right: 34px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 3px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.active,
a.hover_a:hover {
    background: #E4E4EC;
    border-radius: 13px;
    color: #4a2285;
    transition: .5s;
}

.checkbtn {
    color: #E4E4EC;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.hamburger {
    width: 38px;
    height: 28px;
}

#check {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    #logo {
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin-left: 20px;

        font-weight: 700;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }


}



@media (max-width: 858px) {

    #logo {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 70px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .checkbtn {
        display: block;

    }

    ul {
        position: fixed;
        background: #201449;
        background-image: url(../images/menu.jpg);
        background-position: top left;
        background-size: cover;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 76vw;
        height: 100%;
        top: -20px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: left;
        transition: all .5s;
        border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
        z-index: 999;

    }

    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 45vw;
        margin-bottom: -45vw;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        font-weight: 700;





    }

    nav ul li a {

        font-size: 9.5vw;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background: none;
        color: #e4e4ec;
        float: none;
        margin: 0;





    }


    a.hover_a:hover,
    a.active {

        border-radius: 0;
        background: none;
        color: #381f84;
        transition: .5s;
    }

    #check:checked ~ ul {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check">
            <label for="check" class="checkbtn"><img src="images/menu.png" class="hamburger" alt="hamburger">
            </label>
            <a href="index.html" id="logo">
                LOGO
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active buttons hover_a" href=""><b>HOME</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="buttons hover_a"><b>GALLERY</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="buttons hover_a"><b>INFORMATION</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="buttons hover_a"><b>CONTACT</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Hello. It is not clear what you want :) What result do you want?

Comment: Brother @sergeykuznetsov I think he wants to go for a mobile-first approach and not the desktop-first approach. His whole logic will kind of reverse. :) May be he has that in mind. God knows ;). Anyways, you are nice person bro. Are you working or a freelancer Sergey?

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather, yes, brother, I also thought so at first, but I thought that I would clarify with the author of the question :) I work in an it-company, full stack. And you?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Hello, I would like to make it mobile first.

Comment: @Windripper, I understood you. Now I will give a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know exactly how you wanted it, but I did it on my own. If there are additional requests, then tell me about them, and I will correct or finalize. Most importantly, your decision is based on the `float` rules.

Never use these `float` rules!

```css
#logo {   
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

nav ul {
    /*float: right;*/
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {

    color: #E4E4EC;
    background-color: #4A2285;
    border-radius: 13px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-right: 34px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 3px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.active,
a.hover_a:hover {
    background: #E4E4EC;
    border-radius: 13px;
    color: #4a2285;
    transition: .5s;
}

.checkbtn {
    color: #E4E4EC;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.hamburger {
    width: 38px;
    height: 28px;
}

#check {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    #logo {      
        color: #E4E4EC;
        font-size: 50px;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin-left: 54px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
}



@media (min-width: 858px) {

    /*#logo {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 70px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }*/

    .checkbtn {
        display: block;
    }

    ul {
        position: absolute;
        background: #201449;
        background-image: url(../images/menu.jpg);
        background-position: top left;
        background-size: cover;
        opacity: 1;
        /*width: 76vw;*/
        height: 100vh;
        top: -20px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: left;
        transition: all .5s;
        border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        /*margin-top: 45vw;
        margin-bottom: -45vw;*/
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        /*font-size: 9.5vw;*/
        border-radius: 0px;
        background: none;
        color: #e4e4ec;
        /*float: none;*/
        margin: 0;
    }


    a.hover_a:hover,
    a.active {

        border-radius: 0;
        background: none;
        color: #381f84;
        transition: .5s;
    }

    #check:checked ~ ul {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check">
            <label for="check" class="checkbtn"><img src="images/menu.png" class="hamburger" alt="hamburger">
            </label>
            <a href="index.html" id="logo">
                LOGO
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active buttons hover_a" href=""><b>HOME</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="buttons hover_a"><b>GALLERY</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="buttons hover_a"><b>INFORMATION</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="buttons hover_a"><b>CONTACT</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: @Windripper, Is that what you need? If you have questions, I can improve the code.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, this is what I needed, I already edited it and made is as I wanted to from the start. Really appreciate the effort! I commented here yesterday, but for some reasons the comment did not post :(.

Comment: @Windripper, you can duplicate the comment if it is still relevant :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't change the second media query (as that had to be a maximum and couldn't be a minimum). However, if you were wondering what your code would look like with the first media parameter being a minimum (and don't mind the screen oversizing), then this should do it:

```
#logo {
    color: #E4E4EC;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-left: 54px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {

    color: #E4E4EC;
    background-color: #4A2285;
    border-radius: 13px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-right: 34px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 3px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.active,
a.hover_a:hover {
    background: #E4E4EC;
    border-radius: 13px;
    color: #4a2285;
    transition: .5s;
}

.checkbtn {
    color: #E4E4EC;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.hamburger {
    width: 38px;
    height: 28px;
}

#check {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    #logo {
        // Configure your maximum media query here
    }
@media (min-width: 859px) {
    #logo {
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin-left: 20px;

        font-weight: 700;
// Media query that changed
    }

    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }


}



@media (max-width: 858px) {

    #logo {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 70px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .checkbtn {
        display: block;

    }

    ul {
        position: fixed;
        background: #201449;
        background-image: url(../images/menu.jpg);
        background-position: top left;
        background-size: cover;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 76vw;
        height: 100%;
        top: -20px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: left;
        transition: all .5s;
        border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
        z-index: 999;

    }

    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 45vw;
        margin-bottom: -45vw;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        font-weight: 700;





    }

    nav ul li a {

        font-size: 9.5vw;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background: none;
        color: #e4e4ec;
        float: none;
        margin: 0;





    }


    a.hover_a:hover,
    a.active {

        border-radius: 0;
        background: none;
        color: #381f84;
        transition: .5s;
    }

    #check:checked ~ ul {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, not exactly what I wanted, but thank you anyways for the effort. :)